# Should error/ack message be constructed in the client or in server?

Tags: web-development, web-services, error-handling

Should messages that will be shown to the client be resolved in the client-side or in the server-side? Any design (dis)advantages that you can think of between the two approaches? If the system maintains sensitive information and different sets of information is maintained by users with different sets of authorities, would exposing all the message templates in the client-side be security a issue?

Below is the sample logic that will construct the messages for client- and server-side:

**Client handling:**

```
httpService.post('/someEndpoint', requestBody)
  .subscribe(json => {
    if(json.errorCode) {
      // the error service will retrieve the error template
      // for such errorCode and replace placeholder with
      // values from the requestBody
      errorService.alert(json.errorCode, requestBody);
    }
  });
```

**Server handling:**

```
if(hasErrors) {
  // sets the response error code and error message
  apiResponse.error(errorCode, requestBody);
}
```

*Client callback:*

```
httpService.post('/someEndpoint', requestBody)
  .subscribe(json => {
    if(json.errorCode) {
      errorService.alert(json.message);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually a very good question, and very keen of you to ask.  I think for localization purposes, this role is generally left to the client, passing only an error code, not to mention that the message is more succinct.  However, it also tends to be very difficult to work with when errors occur without a proper documentation or client to handle them.

Just be mindful that even if the client hides the error message, whatever is sent to the client is public information unless you're using https, so you should be careful to never provide too many details of the problem and even less so for problems likely created as a consequence of security issues.